# What does the Python naming convention with single/double underscore before a function mean?

Tags: python, naming-conventions, name-mangling

I am unsure how to phrase the question I am asking so feel free to change the title.

Currently, I am working on an existing python codebase and came across this "style" and hope to understand the benefits for using it.

for example,

```
Class Pokemon(object):
   def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

   def _catch(self, pokeball):
       ''' actual implementation here'''

   def catch(self, pokeball):
       _catch(pokeball)
```

You may notice that calls to the catch() function will be rerouted to the _catch() function. I understand that an underscore before a function could be meant to prevent accidental overriding of the function.

EDIT: I think the title should be modified again, I understand what the underscores mean however I was unsure of why we use a catch() and _catch() as we obviously want to expose the function with catch() but decide to stick the implementation within _catch().

Comment: It acts like a protected variable, it's accessible but not visible. A private member would have two underscores with the exception of special methods. They would be both inaccessible an invisible.

Comment: it is called "name mangling" in python, it is used to simulate a kind of private variable or function etc

Comment: Strictly those are methods, rather than functions. I retitled and tagged for you.

Comment: I think what you're really asking is about this general design pattern, which just happens to often involve using single-underscore-named methods in Python (and protected methods in some other languages), but doesn't necessarily require them, and isn't the only reason for them. I'm not sure what the right way to put that is.

Comment: If someone knows what the names are for the two common design patterns here (base class calls a bunch of subclass methods so they can override small core parts of the behavior, or subclass calls base class methods to provide the never-overridden core parts of the behavior), that might be helpful. Maybe template engine and something-else engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, this kind of design is used in two related (but nearly-opposite) patterns, which I don't know the "design patterns" names for. (I think they both include "engine", and one includes "template", if that helps.)

---

For the first, the idea is to allow a subclass to override the public `catch` method to, say, add a bit of extra work before or after the core implementation, but still call the `_catch` method to do most of the work. For example:

```
Class Pokemon(object):
     def __init__(self, name):
          self.name = name

     def _catch(self, pokeball):
         ''' actual implementation here'''
         # hundreds of lines of complex code
         print(pokeball)
         return pokeball

     def catch(self, pokeball):
         print('Gotta catch em all')
         return self._catch(pokeball)

class Pikachu(Pokemon):
     def catch(self, pokeball):
         print('Pikachu')
         return self._catch(pokeball)
```

This allows `Pikachu` to override the "non-core" part of the implementation, which is only a few lines, without overriding the "core" part, which is hundreds of lines.

This pattern isn't nearly as common in Python as it is in, say, Java, but it does sometimes make sense.

---

For the other, the idea is to have the base class break the implementation up into separate pieces, each of which can be overridden by the subclass without having to replace everything else. For example:

```
class Pokemen(object):
    def catch(self, pokeball):
        self._wake_up()
        if not self._check_ready() return False
        try:
            return self._catch(pokeball)
        except SillyError:
            return False
        finally:
            self.consider_sleeping()
```

---

So, why use a leading underscore?

The leading single underscore means "private by convention". For a method name, in particular,<sup>*</sup> it's a hint *to the human reader* that something is not part of the API. Anyone who wants to use a `Pokemon` object should not call `_catch` on it, because that method is an implementation detail—it may change or even go away in future versions, it may make assumptions about the object's state that aren't guaranteed to always be true, etc. But `catch` should always be safe to call.

Often this is a good match for something that you'd make a `protected` method in Java or C++, which is exactly what you'd use for both of these design patterns in those languages, even though it doesn't really mean the same thing.

---

A leading double underscore (without a trailing double underscore) means something different. In a method name or other attribute, it means the name should be "mangled" so that it's harder for a subclass or superclass to accidentally call it, or override it, when it intended to define and use its own private name instead.

Often, this is a good match for something that you'd make a `private` method or member in Java or C++, but it's even farther from that than a single underscore is from `protected`.

---

<sub>* In a few other places, it actually does have a tiny bit more meaning. For example, a module global with a leading underscore will be skipped by `from mod import *` if you didn't specify an `__all__` in `mod`.</sub>

Comment: thank you! The part where a subclass could add additional implementation and still call self._catch() after, was what I was missing in my understanding.

Comment: See below for more on the difference between double and single underscores.